# Changing style elements above and below the visible part of the scroll (those that are hidden)

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a long tree element (mat-tree angular) in a `<div>` tag of fixed height with scroll. How can I change elements that are hidden outside the `<div>` (display: none)? Accordingly, when scrolling, the style should change

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear with your question. but it sounds like you may need to look what lazy-loading is.

Comment: I apologize for my confused thoughts and broken language. I have a tree with 10,000 elements. Virtual scrolling does not work on elements of the type I am using. Therefore, I want to programmatically hide elements outside the user's direct line of sight.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs and supported browsers, you might have to use `IntersectionObserver` OR `scroll` event subscription / interval polling + `document.elementFromPoint()`. See:
https://caniuse.com/#search=intersectionobserver
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 0):

Well your answer is quite vague... But if you like to style elements based on their screen location you will have no luck with css and would have to calculate the position of the element and the current screen via java-script and do some javascript manipulations on the found objects...

that said:
don't do this.

First question:
1.) What is the problem?
2.) What do you want to achieve?

As @Vivek Vikranth also commented there are some well established things out there that COULD help... but your idea is to unclear yet.

Comment: I have a tree with 10,000 elements. Virtual scrolling does not work on elements of the type I am using. Therefore, I want to programmatically hide elements outside the user's direct line of sight